# Diverse resource of problems to show merits of different languages

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

I'd like to learn a few more languages to "expand my mind" a bit, and I find working through problems the best way to learn. I have been doing most of my programming in C, sometimes C++, and perl. With these tools, I seem to be able to solve the problems I encounter, but you know the expression "when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail?" I feel like I am stuck in a single paradigm, and I would like to change.

What I'm looking for is a resource similar to Project Euler, but with more generic/real world problems(Project Euler is very mathematical) which highlight the benefits of different languages. The idea would then be to work through the problem set with each language and note the relative difficulty of completing each problem in the given language.

1) Does such a resource exist?

2) What are some problems you would include? Remember: these should show the strengths of each language.

Thanks!

Comment: One interesting way to start would be to search for "code golf". Most of the problems aren't real, but at least they're (mostly) non-mathematical.

Comment: @Jerry: I learned perl reading/doing code golfs. But they tend to be small, and wouldn't show, for example, how OO paradigm simplifies implementation.

Comment: Sounds like a job for CodeOverflow :-)

Comment: @ Gilbert: if you'd like to participate, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13188/software-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeChef (http://www.codechef.com/) and Sphere Online Judge (https://www.spoj.pl/problems/classical/) both look like good options for you. Their problems aren't necessarily practical, but they are less explicitly mathematical than Project Euler, and their judges accepts programs written in plenty of languages. The Python wiki recommends a few others (http://wiki.python.org/moin/ProblemSets), but they aren't quite as flexible.

I haven't used either site, so I can't recommend any specific problems. Just make sure to include some logic problems so you can revel in the awesomeness of prolog :)