# Toy projects for new programers

Tags: language-agnostic

When I was first started teaching myself programming, after finishing a tutorial I would feel like I still couldn't do anything in the language. So, I looked around to find something to work on. Since I had just learned a few of the basics, the amount of work involved in finding, reading and adding to an open source project seemed insurmountable. Instead I started on a couple toy projects, which ended up being incredibly beneficial.

Having seen a lot of questions from beginners similar to "what should I do now?" and a lot of answers similar to "start working for an open source project" has made me think there has to be better advice for a new programmer. While working on an open source project surely gives great experience, there is a perceptible barrier to entry.

Instead, I think it would be great if new programmers were prodded towards working on a toy program related to some interest they have. Since there are so many directions that programming can take you, I think it would be interesting to list some simple (but fun/rewarding) projects grouped by the direction the new programmer is looking to pursue. Such as:

**Game Design:**

Write a text adventure (like Zork)

**Natural Language Processing:**

Create a program that writes meaningless, but grammatically valid essays.

Comment: there isn't really anything "toy" about the engine that ran all the Infocom games. I would suggest something simpler like an interactive BlackJack game.

Comment: blackjack is actually quite a lot of fun, I did just the same when I taught myself some of the intricacies of the game many years ago.  when I discovered how much like work it was to utilize those skills I decided I would rather continue in software :)

Comment: @fuzzy: The engine doesn't have to be complex. When I first learned BASIC in HS, we would make and share text-based adventure games amongst ourselves.

Comment: you specifically name Zork which qualifies the complexity of the solution, a beginner isn't going to write Zork, so I stick by my suggestion, Zork ( which appears simple, isn't ) and is a bad suggestion for a beginner to tackle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think that a [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/) approach might be better... programmers can still pick topics of interests, but they're actually working for a prize on a REAL project and they get **feedback**. Frankly speaking, TopCoder is a bit of a bloat and as far as I can tell, they don't allow people to make free competitions. It would be great if there is a TopCoder/StackOverflow type of site: people can submit code, get voted on their implementation and just have a good time!

I'll even pitch my idea, I'm starting to work on my own version of TopCoder/StackOverflow hybrid monstrosity called [MyDevArmy](http://www.mydevarmy.com/) (although I have not done anything so far except buy the domain).

Comment: You can use the SO engine. Check out  http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq to get details. Its free! I support this idea.

Comment: @Adam, good idea... I've created a project on area51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13188/software-development

Answer (score 4):

I recently asked a similar question ([Diverse resource of problems to show merits of different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163471/diverse-resource-of-problems-to-show-merits-of-different-languages)) and got links to sites that provide problem sets, as well as validation. Check out:

http://www.codechef.com/

https://www.spoj.pl/problems/classical/

http://wiki.python.org/moin/ProblemSets

http://projecteuler.net/

Although these problems don't oftem amount to projects, they are still interesting. I'm interested in seeing what people come up with here.

Answer (score 0):

Write a program which renders Wolfram automata (esp. [Rule 110](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110)).

See [YelloSoft](http://www.yellosoft.us/automata) for example code.

Comment: Would this fall under mathematics as an area of interest? Or something having to do with turing completeness?

Comment: Categorization is as as arbitrary as your question is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing a Blackjack simulation.  Choose whichever strategy you want for the first run.

Next, start adding additional runs for different strategies like hitting/standing when your hand's value is 15 vs. 16 vs. 17 vs. 18, and whether the hand is soft or hard (an ace's value being counted as 1 or 11).  The dealer's strategy [will be constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack#Basic_strategy), as they really are in casinos.

By the end, your program will run, say, 1000 instances of each strategy combination.  It will print out a summary of the rate of hand wins (percentage of times you beat the dealer) for each stand value and hard/soft combination.

This is easily one of my favorite projects I've done and it can really cement some techniques in the language of your choosing.  Plus, if you have the initiative to start learning some of the (fairly simple) discrete math that's involved in coming up with the odds of these situations as a side project, you can come away with an even better experience.  Who knows, maybe you could ditch this computer stuff and take up card counting?

Comment: The only problem with counting cards is that it's at least as much work as software development.  oh yeah, and the fact that your boss doesn't kick you out when you get really proficient at software :)